# Can I replace Union all with any kind on joins?

Tags: sql, join, select, toad, union-all

I have the below query for negative testing, But I want to replace the `union all` if possible.

```
select A.*
from A
join B
on A.COL1=B.COL1
where B.COL3 is null

union all

select A.*
from A
join B
on A.COL2=B.COL4
where B.COL5 is null;
```

Need to get data from both SQL without using `union all`

Comment: Don't spam DBMS tags. Update your post with only the DBMS you're using.

Comment: Why should this UNION ALL be replaced by JOIN? What advantage do you expect from that?

Comment: Note UNION ALL may return doubles. Collapsed WHERE will not. Decide on what is the behavior you want.

Answer (score 2):

You could combine the two queries into a single join and collapse the `where` condition into it:

```sql
select A.* 
from   A 
join   B on (A.COL1 = B.COL1 and B.COL3 is null) or 
            (A.COL2 = B.COL4 and B.COL5 is null)
```

Comment: -Thank you Sir, But what if the where conditions are different.

Comment: @Tanmaya you could colapse it to the `join` clause and have two different branches of the join - `(a.col1 = b.col2 AND some_condition) OR (a.col2 = b.col4 AND some_other_condition)`.

Comment: Note that the second select has B.COL5 is null.

Comment: @jarlh The question was edited after I posted the answer (the original had `b.col3 is null` in both queries). I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only after data from Table A you don't need the join to table B at all and can re-write this as an Exists...

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM B 
              WHERE A.COL1=B.COL1 and B.COL3 is null)
   OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM B 
              WHERE A.COL2=B.COL4 and B.COL5 is null)
```

But this has likely has two issues:

1. I'm pretty sure if you look at the execution plan for both; you'll find the union all is more efficient because it operates at a set level instead of a row level ad the OR needed in this is slower.
2. This will return 1 record from A instead of 2 from that of a union all.  had it been a union; this should/would return the same results and avoid the union.  But simply put you want the same data from A twice (or more depending on cardinality of joins)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM A 
JOIN B ON (A.COL1 = B.COL1 OR A.COL2 = B.COL4) AND B.COL3 IS NULL;
```

Comment: Instead of using Seperate WHERE clause, it is preferable to put it also in the joining condition. In many scenarios, it works slightly faster

Comment: Don't comment your own answer, but edit it to add further information.

Comment: Thank you @AnujKumar,  but the where conditions are different , Can you please review once.